# "ignoring potentially dangerous server-supplied filename" in pscp

Tags: linux, putty, scp, pscp

I want to copy some file from a remote Linux system to my Windows PC using `pscp` (from PuTTY). I wrote a small script that should copy all `.png` files in a directory on my server:

```
pscp -unsafe root@169.60.147.[redacted]:/root/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/results/summer2winter_yosemite_cyclegan/test_latest/images/*.png C:\files\tests\images
```

I'm using the `-unsafe` option because whenever I run this command, I get this output:

```
ignoring potentially dangerous server-supplied filename '2011-05-29 10:20:21_rec_A.png'
ignoring potentially dangerous server-supplied filename '2011-07-06 16:55:20_real_B.png'
..
ignoring potentially dangerous server-supplied filename '2011-08-30 23:13:10_real_A.png'
pscp: wildcard '*.png' matched no files
```

However, when I use the `-unsafe` option the command will still output those same results. [Here](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter5.html) is some documentation on `pscp` that I read over thoroughly, to no avail. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-unsafe` won't help with this.

The problem is that your file names contain colons. Colons are not allowed in Windows file names.